# Get value of input with keypress and capture key pressed

Tags: javascript, html, keypress

I am using a `keypress` `event` and I want to get the `value` within the `input` box after a key has been pressed. I also would like to capture which key has been pressed. In [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gpd7Lzoh/) I am only allowing the user to enter numbers into the `input` box (I know there is a `number` `type` for inputs). I am using `setTimeout` to get the `value` from the `input` box. Is there a better way to accomplish this? Would this ever fail?

```js
var elTest = document.getElementById('test');
var elResult = document.getElementById('result');

function isNumber(evt, el) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  setTimeout(function () {
    elResult.textContent = el.value;
  }, 0);
  return true;
}

elTest.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  return isNumber(e, this);
});
```

```html
<input id='test' />
<div id='result'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a combination of keydown and keyup event listeners due to the fact that the keypress event doesn't fire on backspace or delete.

On keydown, check for number, backspace/delete input and prevent if needed.

On keyup, update the result output from the input value.

```
var elTest = document.getElementById('test');
var elResult = document.getElementById('result');

function allowInput(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    var isNumber = charCode < 58 && charCode > 47;
    var isBackspace = charCode == 8 || charCode == 46;
    return isNumber || isBackspace;
}

elTest.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (!allowInput(e)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

elTest.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    elResult.textContent = this.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just got the event and this objects mixed during the function call. If you use this.value, then the the number won't be there yet, but if you use the event.key (which gives the string value of the key) then you should get the proper output.

```js
var elTest = document.getElementById('test');
var elResult = document.getElementById('result');

function isNumber(evt, el) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } else {
    elResult.textContent += evt.key;
  }
  return true;
}

elTest.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  return isNumber(e, this);
});
```

```html
<input id='test' />
<div id='result'>

</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't cover the case where a number is removed from the value and keypress doesn't fire when backspace/delete are pressed so those keys would not be prevented.

Comment: @dhudson, I wasn't trying to solve for all cases, but rather trying to get Anthony on the right track. Agreed that the keyup for input works to grab the input value when delete or backspace are used and the above code does not solve for that.